# Django: AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'current_hours'

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pycharm

This has been happening to me multiple times where it does not recognize the fields I have made for an object.
Here is trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ResNet\Desktop\Scheduler\Scheduler\Scheduler_App\models.py", line 106, in init
  kevin.get_current_hours(w)
File "C:\Users\ResNet\Desktop\Scheduler\Scheduler\Scheduler_App\models.py", line 240, in get_current_hours
  self.curent_hours.save()
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'curent_hours'
```

Here is most of models.py:

```
class Week(models.Model):
    """ Base class for the workweek. """
    dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    days = models.ManyToManyField('Day')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, dt):
        week = cls(dt=dt)
        return week

    def add_staff(self, days_availability, num_qhs, employee):  # untested
        for q in range(num_qhs):
            qh = dt2qh(self, days_availability[q].dt)
            qh.staff.add(employee)
            qh.staff.save()
            # self.save() -- unsure


class Day(models.Model):
    """ Base class for the day. """
    dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    total_available_qhs = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    total_available_qhs.null = True
    hours = models.ManyToManyField('Hour')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, dt):
        day = cls(dt=dt)
        return day

    def get_total_available_qhs(self, employees):  # untested
        self.total_available_qhs = employees.total_available_qhs_per_day(self.dt)
        return self.total_available_qhs


class Hour(models.Model):
    """ Base class for the hour. """
    dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    qhs = models.ManyToManyField('QuarterHour')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, dt):
        hour = cls(dt=dt)
        return hour


class QuarterHour(models.Model):
    """ Base class for the quarter hour. """
    dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField('Employee', related_name='Employee')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, dt):
        qh = cls(dt=dt)
        return qh


def init():  # Creates the week structure
    w = Week.create(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 13))
    w.save()
    # print(w.days.get(dt=datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 13)).dt)
    for i in range(5):  # Mon - Fri
        d = Day.create(w.dt + datetime.timedelta(days=i))
        d.save()
        for j in range(11):  # 8am - 7pm
            h = Hour.create(d.dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=j + 8))
            h.save()
            for k in range(4):  # 0m, 15m, 30m, 45m
                qh = QuarterHour.create(h.dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15 * k))
                qh.save()
                h.qhs.add(qh)
            h.save()
            d.hours.add(h)
        d.save()
        w.days.add(d)
    w.save()

    # Week structure test
    '''for d in w.days.all():
        for h in d.hours.all():
            for qh in h.qhs.all():
                print(qh.dt)'''

    # dt2qh test
    '''dttm = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 14, 18, 45)
    print(dttm, 'should =', dt2qh(w, dttm).dt)'''


    # Employee class testing
    kevin = Employee.create('kevin', 10, 2)
    kevin.save()
    for d in range(5):
        for h in range(11):
            for q in range(4):
                if d > 1:
                    qh = w.days.all()[d].hours.all()[h].qhs.all()[q]
                    qh.staff.add(kevin)
                    qh.staff.get(name='kevin').save()
                    #qh.save()
    kevin.get_current_hours(w)
    for e in kevin.current_hours.all():
        print(e.dt)
        print(kevin.name)
    for d in range(5):
        for h in range(11):
            for q in range(4):
                print(w.days.all()[d].hours.all()[h].qhs.all()[q].dt)
                print(w.days.all()[d].hours.all()[h].qhs.all()[q].staff.all()[0].name)


def dt2qh(week, dt):  # converts from datetime to quarter hour
    d = (dt - week.dt).days
    h = dt.hour - 8
    q = int(math.floor(dt.minute / 15))
    # print(d, h, q)
    return week.days.all()[d].hours.all()[h].qhs.all()[q]


class Employee(models.Model):
    """ Base class for a employee."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    requested_hours = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    requested_days = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    availability = models.ManyToManyField('QuarterHour', related_name='availability')
    current_hours = models.ManyToManyField('QuarterHour', related_name='current_hours')
    # add a+, project work, front desk booleans

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, nm, rh, rd):
        employee = cls(name=nm, requested_hours=rh, requested_days=rd)
        return employee

    def get_current_hours(self, week):  # untested
        for d in range(5):
            for h in range(11):
                for q in range(4):
                    qh = week.days.all()[d].hours.all()[h].qhs.all()[q]
                    for s in range(len(qh.staff.all())):
                        if qh.staff.all()[s].name == self.name and qh not in enumerate(self.current_hours.all()):
                            self.current_hours.add(qh)
                            self.curent_hours.save()
                            break

    def get_num_current_hours(self):  # untested
        return len(self.current_hours.all())

    def hours_fulfilled(self):  # untested
        return self.get_num_current_hours() >= self.requested_hours * 4

    # untested
    def add_availability(self, start, end, week):  # start/end datetimes can     only be from same day
        temp = start
        while temp < end:
            self.availability.add(dt2qh(week, temp))
            self.availability.save()
            temp += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)

    def availability_for_day(self, dt):  # untested
        temp = []
        for qh in self.availability.all():
            if qh.dt.day == dt.day:
                temp.append(qh)
        return temp

    # tries to even out peoples hours
    def suggested_qhs_per_day(self):  # untested
        return math.floor(self.requested_hours * 4 / self.requested_days)


class Employees(models.Model):
    """ Class for list of employees """
    list = models.ManyToManyField('Employee')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, list):
        employees = cls(list=list)
        return employees

    def total_available_qhs_per_day(self, day):  # day is a datetime
        temp = 0
        for e in self.list.all():
            temp += len(e.availability_for_day(day))
        return temp

    def available_employees(self, day):  # day is a datetime
        temp = []
        for e in self.list.all():
            if len(e.availability_for_day(day)) > 0:
                temp.append(e)
        return temp
```

Here is the only migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Day',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('dt', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('total_available_qhs', models.DecimalField(default=0, blank=True, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, null=True)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Employee',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('requested_hours', models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)),
            ('requested_days', models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Employees',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('list', models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.Employee')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Hour',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('dt', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='QuarterHour',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('dt', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('staff', models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.Employee', related_name='Employee')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Week',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)),
            ('dt', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
            ('days', models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.Day')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='hour',
        name='qhs',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.QuarterHour'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='employee',
        name='availability',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.QuarterHour', related_name='availability'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='employee',
        name='current_hours',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.QuarterHour', related_name='current_hours'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='day',
        name='hours',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='Scheduler_App.Hour'),
    ),
]
```

I'm new to django and this has completely halted me. I just switched over from sqlite3 to mysql because I thought it was the cause of the problem but, alas, no use. I've overcome this error earlier a few times by messing around with field that errors and so it makes a AlterField in a second migration but that hasn't worked this time. I have also tried manually modifying the migrations in several ways to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your traceback is indicating that you are missing an `r` in `current_hours`.**

It should not be

```
self.curent_hours.save() # missing an `r` in 'current'
```

but instead be

```
self.current_hours.save()
```

Notice the missing `r` in `current_hours` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a typo.  Change self.curent_hours.save() to self.current_hours.save()